# Inputting into a pointer and returning the methods of that pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

Sorry about the title, I didn't know how to word it. Basically I have a null pointer to a shape object and when some inputs have been entered I want them to be the values for this shape object;

```
shape *s = (shape *) 0;
cin >> *s;
if (s)
    cout << "Shape" << (*s) << '\n';
else if (! cin.bad())
    cout << "Read reached EOF\n";
else
    cout << "Read failed\n";
```

I've overloaded the << operator like so, which calls a draw method of whatever shape it is;

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, shape &s){
    s.draw();
    return os;
}
```

Where I'm struggling is trying to reading my values into the pointer. The input type for my data is like so;

```
< Circle: (3,1) 1 >
```

I've overloaded the >> operator;

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &is, shape &s){
  char lessthan, greaterthan, opbrkt, clsbrkt, comma;
  string shape_type;
  double x1, y1, r, x2, y2, x3, y3;

  if (is >> lessthan) {
    if ('<' != lessthan) {
      is.setstate(ios::badbit);
      return is;
    }

    //Circle implemntation
    if(is >> shape_type && shape_type == "Circle:"){
      if(!((is >> opbrkt) && (opbrkt = '('))) {
        is.setstate(ios::badbit);
        return is;
      }

      cout << "Yes" << i++;
      if(!(is >> x1)){
        is.setstate(ios::badbit);
        return is;
      }

      if(!(is >> comma && comma == ',')){
        is.setstate(ios::badbit);
        return is;
      }

      if(!(is >> y1)){
        is.setstate(ios::badbit);
        return is;
      }


      if(!(is >> clsbrkt && clsbrkt == ')')) {
        is.setstate(ios::badbit);
        return is;
      }

      if(!(is >> r)){
        is.setstate(ios::badbit);
        return is;
      }

      if(!(is >> clsbrkt && clsbrkt == '>')) {
        is.setstate(ios::badbit);
        return is;
      }
    }

    return is;
  }

  return is;
}
```

This basically picks up that it's a circle and puts the relevant into variables for later use, but how do I get this data into the 's' pointer to point at what now should be a circle object?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read into a pointer. You can only read into an object:

```
shape s;
std::cin >> s;

// if you need a pointer for some reason:
shape * p = &s;
```

If the actual object is polymorphic in nature, you might like to produce a wrapper class, perhaps like so:

```
class Shape
{
  ShapeImpl * impl;  // or better, `std::unique_ptr<ShapeImpl>`
  //
}

class ShapeImpl { virtual ~ShapeImpl() { } };
class Circle : public ShapeImpl { /* ... */ }
```

Otherwise, you might just forgo the idea of overloading the stream extraction operator and instead provide your own deserialization function:

```
std::unique_ptr<Shape> read_shape(std::istream & is)
{
  // ...
  std::unique_ptr<Shape> p(new Circle);
  // ...
  return p;
}

std::unique_ptr<Shape> s(read_shape(std::cin));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ouch!!!

```
shape *s = (shape *) 0;
cin >> *s;
```

You just dereferenced a null pointer. That is undefined behavior. What you need is a factory method.

```
shape* input()
{
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    if(name == "circle")
    {
       double radius;
       cin >> radius;
       return new Circle(radius)
    }
    else if(name == "Rectangle")
    {
        ....
        return new Rectangle(...);
    }
    else if .... 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Armen! Where would I put this function, would I call this within the overloading of >>??

Comment: This could be a freestanding function.

Comment: Armen, sorry I'm an absolute rank amateur here! How do I call the input() for the 'cin>> *s' part?!

Comment: @robb077: `shape *s = input();`

Comment: Armen, thanks again but I cannot change the 'shape *s = (shape *) 0' part of the code, this will be used to test our program! Can I implement this anywhere else?